# Parse.com query returning nil for object and crashing app

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery, objectid

This should normally be easy and straight forward but I'm struggling to find an answer. I want to be able to assign the objectId to an array so when I want to update a column I can use `query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId`. I'm performing the initial query and assigning the values found to a dictionary. Unfortunately the app crashes when I try to assign the column objectId and I get `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"classname")
    query.whereKey("available", equalTo:true)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock( {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count)")

            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {

                    let x = dict(aColumn1: (object["column1"] as! String), aColumn2: (object["column2"] as! String), aId: (object["objectId"] as! String))

                    dictArr.append(x)

                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
        }
    )
```

Comment: this line "let x = array(aColumn1: (object["column1"] as! String), aColumn2: (object["column2"] as! String), aId: (object["objectId"] as! String))" is generating issue. as content within object for either column1 or column2 results into nil and by writing as! you are forcing wrapping of nil which results into crash.

Comment: column1 and column2 return a result. If I get rid of `aId: (object["objectId"] as! String)`, the program runs fine without an error and it populates the array. objectId is generating the issue which is odd because it is auto generated for every class in parse.

Comment: yes, i know it is autogenerated from parse, are you using includekey method to include object of that class, as initially when i was new with parse, i forgot to add and then was getting nill for objectid.

Comment: Where would I need to add the includekey method?

Comment: query.includeKey("classname")

Comment: Just tried it and it still returns a nil

Comment: can you print log of single object here..

Comment: In order to access the objectId of a PFObject you use myObject.objectId. You shouldn't use a dictionary key. objectId is a property in the PFObject class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your array like this:

```
let x = [(object["column1"] as! String),(object["column2"] as! String), (object["objectId"] as! String)]
```

But seems more like you want a dictionary instead, if that is the case you can try this:

```
let x = [("aColumn1": (object["column1"] as! String), "aColumn2": (object["column2"] as! String), "aId": (object["objectId"] as! String))]
```

Comment: aId is already given a type of a String. If i delete `aId: (object["objectId"] as! String)` I'm able to retrieve the objects and store them. objectId is the only one that causes an issue.